# New JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have been writing up a java script library to convert html to pdf, all is going well. Before i continue any further i would like to know how users feel about these optional html attributes for rendering the pdf.

```
<div class='PDF' PDF_WIDTH='612' PDF_WIDTH='792' PDF_FONT_SIZE='16' PDF_FROMLEFT='20' PDF_FROMTOP='42' PDF_LS='22'>
<span id='PDF_LINE'>Ollie is an eel.</span>
<span id='PDF_LINE' PDF_CENTER=TRUE>He likes his home in a jar.</span>
<span id='PDF_LINE' PDF_CENTER=TRUE>When he comes out he swims over his jar.</span>
<span id='PDF_LINE' PDF_CENTER=TRUE>He swims under his jar.</span>
<span id='PDF_LINE'>He swims through his jar.</span>
<span id='PDF_LINE'>He swims around his jar.</span>
<span id='PDF_LINE'>When he is done, he swims back into his jar.</span>
<span id='PDF_LINE'>Now there are two eels, Ollie and Izzy. When Ollie and Izzy come out they can swim over, under, through, around, and back into their jar together.</span>
</div>
```

The render uses text wrap to the nearest word detected. For example the line:

"Now there are two eels, Ollie and Izzy. When Ollie and Izzy come out they can swim over, under, through, around, and back into their jar together."

Would more then likely be larger then the PDF width, so the text wrap may wrap the text to a new line like so..

Now there are two eels, Ollie and Izzy. When Ollie and 
Izzy come out they can swim over, under, through, around, 
and back into their jar together."

The PDF_CENTER attribute centers the text. (alignment right comming soon).

The attributes:

```
 PDF_WIDTH='612' PDF_HEIGHT='792' PDF_FONT_SIZE='16' PDF_FROMLEFT='20' PDF_FROMTOP='42' PDF_LS='22'
```

are all predefined settings, you dont need to use these only if you wish to modify the document.

i am pretty much wrapping up the text rendering and moving on to using images, just want to make sure the syntax is all well with everyone whom might use this library.

Download a sample of the PDF -> https://mega.co.nz/#!ilJDyaqS!fpu6pBxtige6ZTR_UY3oDWb1pCpgJaAkoKI5U3bw0-Q

to render in javascript you would use:

```
$A_PDF('.PDF').literals.PDF_WRITER('.PDF > #PDF_LINE');
```

Is there anything you would change about this library syntax?

Comment: Typo? PDF_WIDTH='792' - anyway I think this may be closed due to opinion based questions are off topic. If the span is centered in the container, I guess it should be centered in the PDF, no?

Comment: oo good point on the centering mpungjan.

Comment: There are libraries that can achieve similar results, however the end of this project there will be support for all options in pdf. such as images, text alignment, positioning, pages, font types, font sizes, font color, all that good stuff.

Comment: And pdf.js by mozilla and other libraries are not good enough?